# Conversion Error on VB Script

Tags: video, vbscript, file-conversion

I am using VB Script to convert ARF files to both MP4 and WMV format. The script uses the API from the Network Recording Player (which is used to view and convert Web-Ex videos which are in ARF format). However, I am experiencing a very strange error. The WMV conversion works fine on whatever machine I try it in but this is not the same with the MP4 which only works on one my machines but doesn't on two other ones I have tried.

The script works by converting all the ARF files located in a particular folder (in my case a folder called "Webex" in the C drive) to both MP4 and WMV and saves them in the same folder. 
When I open the folder after running the script, I can see certain files created during the conversion and once completed only the WMV video remains. The MP4 begins to convert and then stops on certain machines. You can see the "videoname"-mp4.cfg file being created but then it disappears immediately.

Dont really know what the problem is, any help will be appreciated.

Below is my scipt:

```
Option Explicit

'Main

Sub Main
    Dim Path
    Dim a: a = ListDir("C:\Webex\*.arf")
    Dim FileName
    Dim FileName1
    Dim FileName2
    Dim mp4
    Dim wmv
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFile
    Dim objTextFile
    Dim WSHShell
    Dim StrCMDLine
    Dim d: d = ListDir("C:\Webex\*.cfg")
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    For Each FileName In d
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        objFSO.DeleteFile(Filename)
    Next
    For Each FileName In a
        mp4 = 0
        wmv = 0
        'WScript.Echo FileName
        'WScript.Echo Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))
        Dim b: b = ListDir(Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))+".mp4")
        For Each FileName1 In b
            'WScript.Echo FileName1
            mp4 = 1
        Next
        Dim c: c = ListDir(Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))+".wmv")
        For Each FileName2 In c
            'WScript.Echo FileName2
            wmv = 1
        Next
        If mp4 = 0 Then
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))+"-mp4.cfg")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("[Console]")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("inputfile="+Filename)
            objTextFile.WriteLine("media=MP4")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("showui=0")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("[UI]")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("chat=0")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("qa=0")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("largeroutline=1")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("[MP4]")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("outputfile="+Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))+".mp4")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("width=1024")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("height=768")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("framerate=8")
            objTextFile.Close
        End If
        If wmv = 0 Then
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))+"-wmv.cfg")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("[Console]")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("inputfile="+Filename)
            objTextFile.WriteLine("media=WMV")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("showui=0")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("PCAudio=0")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("[UI]")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("largeroutline=0")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("[WMV]")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("outputfile="+Left(Filename,(Len(Filename)-4))+".wmv")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("width=1024")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("height=768")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("videocodec=Windows Media Video 9")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("audiocodec=Windows Media Audio 9.2 Lossless")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("videoformat=default")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("audioformat=default")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("videokeyframes=4")
            objTextFile.WriteLine("maxstream=1000")
            objTextFile.Close
        End If
    Next
    Dim e: e = ListDir("c:\Webex\*.cfg")
    For Each FileName In e
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        StrCMDLine = "cmd /c C: & CD %windir% & C:\ProgramData\WebEx\WebEx\500\nbrplay.exe -Convert " + """" + FileName + """" + " & exit"
        'WScript.Echo StrCMDLine
        wshShell.run StrCMDLine ,0,True
        objFSO.DeleteFile(Filename)
    Next

End Sub

Public Function ListDir (ByVal Path)
    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Path = "" Then Path = "*.*"
    Dim Parent, Filter
    If fso.FolderExists(Path) Then ' Path is a directory
        Parent = Path
        Filter = "*"
    Else
        Parent = fso.GetParentFolderName(Path)
        If Parent = "" Then If Right(Path,1) = ":" Then Parent = Path: Else Parent = "."
        Filter = fso.GetFileName(Path)
        If Filter = "" Then Filter = "*"
    End If
    ReDim a(10)
    Dim n: n = 0
    Dim Folder: Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Parent)
    Dim Files: Set Files = Folder.Files
    Dim File
    For Each File In Files
        If CompareFileName(File.Name,Filter) Then
            If n > UBound(a) Then ReDim Preserve a(n*2)
            a(n) = File.Path
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve a(n-1)
    ListDir = a
End Function

Private Function CompareFileName (ByVal Name, ByVal Filter) ' (recursive)
    CompareFileName = False
    Dim np, fp: np = 1: fp = 1
    Do
        If fp > Len(Filter) Then CompareFileName = np > Len(name): Exit Function
        If Mid(Filter,fp) = ".*" Then ' special case: ".*" at end of filter
            If np > Len(Name) Then CompareFileName = True: Exit Function
        End If
        If Mid(Filter,fp) = "." Then ' special case: "." at end of filter
            CompareFileName = np > Len(Name): Exit Function
        End If
        Dim fc: fc = Mid(Filter,fp,1): fp = fp + 1
        Select Case fc
            Case "*"
            CompareFileName = CompareFileName2(name,np,Filter,fp)
            Exit Function
            Case "?"
            If np <= Len(Name) And Mid(Name,np,1) <> "." Then np = np + 1
            Case Else
            If np > Len(Name) Then Exit Function
            Dim nc: nc = Mid(Name,np,1): np = np + 1
            If StrComp(fc,nc,vbTextCompare)<>0 Then Exit Function
        End Select
    Loop
End Function

Private Function CompareFileName2 (ByVal Name, ByVal np0, ByVal Filter, ByVal fp0)
    Dim fp: fp = fp0
    Dim fc2
    Do ' skip over "*" and "?" characters in filter
        If fp > Len(Filter) Then CompareFileName2 = True: Exit Function
        fc2 = Mid(Filter,fp,1): fp = fp + 1
        If fc2 <> "*" And fc2 <> "?" Then Exit Do
    Loop
    If fc2 = "." Then
        If Mid(Filter,fp) = "*" Then ' special case: ".*" at end of filter
            CompareFileName2 = True: Exit Function
        End If
        If fp > Len(Filter) Then ' special case: "." at end of filter
            CompareFileName2 = InStr(np0,Name,".") = 0: Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    Dim np
    For np = np0 To Len(Name)
        Dim nc: nc = Mid(Name,np,1)
        If StrComp(fc2,nc,vbTextCompare)=0 Then
            If CompareFileName(Mid(Name,np+1),Mid(Filter,fp)) Then
                CompareFileName2 = True: Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    CompareFileName2 = False
End Function
```

Comment: Run this line manually from a command prompt and see what happens. This isn't a VBScript problem.

StrCMDLine = "cmd /c C: & CD %windir% & C:\ProgramData\WebEx\WebEx\500\nbrplay.exe -Convert " + """" + FileName + """" + " & exit"

Comment: Did you deleted a `End If` in the function **ListDir**? Looks like you are trying to combine lines of batch commands into a single Shell command... it won't work. Just use Full Path Names for exe and the media file.

Comment: No I have not deleted a End If in ListDir. I have confirmed that the script run in the other machine (which works fine) is exactly the same as the one run on my machine

Comment: Anyone got any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nathan Rice that this isn't a VBScript problem. You need to retrieve the error that the command line is dumping on your cmd execution.

So try rewriting this:

```
StrCMDLine = "cmd /c C: & CD %windir% & C:\ProgramData\WebEx\WebEx\500\nbrplay.exe -Convert " + """" + FileName + """" + " & exit"
```

to this:

```
dim timelog : timelog = replace(replace(formatdatetime(Now, 3), ":", "-"), " ", "-")
StrCMDLine = "cmd /c C: & CD %windir% & C:\ProgramData\WebEx\WebEx\500\nbrplay.exe -Convert " + """" + FileName + """" + " > C:\dumplog-" + timelog + ".txt & exit"
```

This will allow you to retrieve your command log files for each time and find the errors that the command prompt reported.